# Can't intercept 404 with express node js

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/test-angular.html');
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000");
});
```

When I access the url  `http://localhost:3000/xyz`, which does not exist, I get the standard page saying `Cannot GET /xyz`, instead of my custom error page. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature you're using (`err, req, res, next`) is for **errors**. E.g. a middleware calls `next(new Error('failed'))`. What you need is a regular middleware which simply happens to be the last one that is executed, which means you interpret it as 404 (see answer below).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/test-angular.html');
})

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error.html');
});


//------------------
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error.html');
});
//------------------


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Node usually starts matching endpoints from **top to bottom**.

So first write down all the endpoints of your app, then write an endpoint like below at the end which will be executed when none of your defined endpoints match.

```
 app.get('/path1', handler1);
 app.get('/path2', handler2);
 app.get('/path3', handler3);
 app.get('/*',function (req, res) {
  //This block will executed when user tries to access endpoint other than /path1,/path2,/path3
  // Handle error here
 })
```

Your code should look like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/test-angular.html');
})

app.get('/*',function (req, res) {  //If any of your defined endpoints doesn't match, this block will be executed. 
   res.status(404);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log("Example app listening on port 3000");
});
```